# Set different size or auto-resize for Path in StaticResource Canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, canvas

I'm using a `ResourceDictionary` for all my icons like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Canvas x:Key="Icon.Refresh"
            Width="32" Height="32"
            Clip="F1 M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0">
        <Path Width="28" Height="28"
              Canvas.Left="2" Canvas.Top="2"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Data="..." /> 
    </Canvas>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

And actual XAML:

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource Icon.Refresh}"
        Height="40" 
        Width="40" />
```

This works fine as most of my Buttons are this size. But when I want to use it on smaller Buttons it overflows the button:

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource Icon.Refresh}"
        Height="30" 
        Width="30" />
```

[image: ReloadButton]

Is there a way to set the Size of a `StaticResource` or any other clever thing to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking you could put the `Canvas` inside of a `<ViewBox>` so that it automatically scales down.

Comment: `Canvas` is not needed here.

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, the `Canvas` is not required, accordingly as properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` for the Path. As far as I know, it automatically adds the application (e.g. Blend), which generates these Path's.  Besides, it is very costly for performance keep for each `Path` panel Canvas.

You do not need to store the Width and Height of the resource, instead of add `Stretch="Fill"` to Path:

```
<Button Width="30" Height="30">
    <Path Name="MyPath"              
          Fill="Bisque"
          Stretch="Fill"
          Data="..." />
</Button>
```

Most importantly it is *`Data`* at object Path. You need to do the following:

In Resources `App.xaml`, `<Window.Resources>`, etc. add Path with key:

```
<Path x:Key="MyPath" Data="F1 M 0,0L ..." />
```

And in `Style` or where else use like this:

```
<Path x:Name="MyPathButton"
      ...
      Fill="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}" 
      Data="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyPath}, Path=Data}" />
```

Or doing so: put Data in `Geometry`:

```
<Geometry x:Key="MagnifierIconGeometry">M44,12 C32,12 22,22 22,34 22,46 32,56 44,56 56,56 66,46 66,34 66,22 56,12 44,12z M44,0 C63,0 78,15 78,34 78,53 63,68 44,68 40,68 36.5,67.5 33,66 L32.5,66 14,90 0,79.5 18,55.5 17,55 C13,49 10,42 10,34 10,15 25,0 44,0z</Geometry>
```

And use like this:

```
<Path Data="{StaticResource MagnifierIconGeometry}" 
      Fill="Black"
      Stretch="Fill" />
```

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, but the `ViewBox` solution is way easier to use